# Ordinals defined by successor and union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion, ordinals

Let $M$ be the smallest set of ordinals satisfying

- $0\in M$
- $x\in M\implies x+1\in M$
- $S\subseteq M\implies \bigcup S\in M$

What does $M$ look like? Is it all ordinals? Is it all countable ordinals?

Is there a standard notation for $M$?

Comment: No such set exists. If it did, it would contain all ordinals, and the collection of all ordinals forms a proper class.

Comment: What @qaphla said: there's no such *set*. You can ask about the "smallest such *class*", and then, it's the class of all ordinals. But you'd have to write that definition in Morse-Kelley (MK) set theory, as it quantifies over classes (so it can't be said in NGB, and of course not in ZFC either).

Comment: @BrianO if MK is stronger than ZFC why don't we use it as convention? are there any large disadvantages?

Comment: @shaihorowitz The main disadvantage being that it's essentially a 2nd order theory, so for the purposes of *foundations* it's harder to reason about, much less feel secure about. It's hard enough to wrap one's head around "all sets"; but "all classes" is much harder still. By the way, MK proves the consistency of ZFC, whereas NGB is a conservative extension of ZFC.